# Searching for records using Date >=

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a small table and want to search for records that are >= to June 1, 2021. I did the following

```
Select ApplyDate from zPermitsToCAMA where ApplyDate >=2019-01-01
```

I'm getting Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: Please share more details. What kind of "table" are you using? What have you tried to resolve the given problem?

Comment: You need to use '2019-01-01'

Comment: Or if you actually mean June 1, 2021, then use `where ApplyDate >= '2021-06-01'`

Comment: Without the required quotes around the date literal, the numeric expression is evaluated. (2019 minus 1 minus 1 equals 2017). The integer is converted to a datetime value for the comparison (1905-07-11 00:00:00.000)..

Comment: Thanks Peter B.  That what I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select ApplyDate from zPermitsToCAMA where ApplyDate >= 2019-01-01
```

evaluates to

```
Select ApplyDate from zPermitsToCAMA where ApplyDate >= 2017
```

(start with `2019` and subtract `1` twice)

You want to quote the date

```
Select ApplyDate from zPermitsToCAMA where ApplyDate >= '2019-01-01'
```